# Existence of martingales given some constraint on laws

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $X=(X)_{0\le t\le 1}$ be a continuous martingale starting at $0$, then denote by $\mu$ and $\nu$ the probability laws of $\int_0^1X_t \mathrm{d}t$ and $X_1$. Then it is easy to see that the couple $(\mu,\nu)$ is increasing in convex order, i.e.

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\mathrm{d}\mu(x)~~\le~~\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\mathrm{d}\nu(x)$$

holds for all convex functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ of linear growth, see also "Peacocks and Associated Martingales, with Explicit Constructions" for further details. Now my question is given by probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$, could we give some conditions on the couple $(\mu,\nu)$ such that there exists a continuous martingale $X=(X)_{0\le t\le 1}$ satisfying

$$X_1\sim\mu~~\mbox{and}~~ \int_0^1X_t\mathrm{d}t\sim\nu ?$$

Comment: Indeed, this question is motivated by the characterization of the joint law of $(\sup_{0\le t\le 1}X_t, X_1)$, see e.g. http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0101762#page-1